# T-SQL Select All StoreID and All ItemID two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

tblStores

```
StoreID
1
2
3
```

tblItems

```
ItemID
1
2
3
```

I need a query to show as below:

```
StoreID    ItemID
1          1
1          2
1          3
2          1
2          2
2          3
3          1
3          2
3          3
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tblStores CROSS JOIN tblItems`

Comment: @MartinSmith yikes, right, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblStores
CROSS JOIN tblItems;
```

and use this [link](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php) for more info